# Unable to update Git on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu

I am trying to set up Git on an Ubuntu Machine (I'm using a Samsung Chromebook running Ubuntu 12.04).

When I entered "sudo apt-get install git" and it successfully installed Git 1.79

```
user@ChrUbuntu:~$ git --version
git version 1.7.9.5
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks good so far. What is your question? What problem have you encountered?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

For new installations of Ubuntu I would first try this to get the latest updates

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

For more info on this see https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade

That should solve it but if not, add the repository from these guys https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

This way you don't have to build it, etc.

Comment: I'd rather apt-get than compile any day.

Comment: As a good complement, you might need this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797328/why-is-the-git-subtree-not-working-even-though-i-have-git-1-8-3-2-installed-on

Answer (score 21):

Perhaps you need to build for
[the newest version](http://digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-git-on-ubuntu-12-04)

```
wget git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.8.1.1.tar.gz
tar -zxf git-1.8.1.1.tar.gz
cd git-1.8.1.1
make prefix=/usr/local all
sudo make prefix=/usr/local install
```

Comment: tried ersion 1.8.5.5, doesn't work for me... `done && \
        ./check_bindir "z$bindir" "z$execdir" "$bindir/git-add"` is the last line...

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to upgrade to the latest version of Git, you should do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This will update all your packages, as well as Git.
BTW, latest version of Git on my Kubuntu 12.10 is `1.7.10.4`.

Comment: This will most likely not get you the latest version. The Ubuntu repositories are always behind. You should add the PPA from the "Ubuntu Git Maintainers" team, see @haley's answer.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of some of the answers worked for me. I did...

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do an `apt-get update`?
You might have an outdated package list.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 14.04 I tried the terminal code:

sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade

step to upgrade git.

1.) git --version
    
*to know what git version you had in your computer
2.) sudo apt-get update
    
*update ubuntu
3.) sudo apt-get upgrade
    
*to upgrade software including git
4.) try to git --version

that's it :)