# Why is the `git subtree` not working even though I have git 1.8.3.2 installed on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: git, ubuntu, git-subtree

I am about to deploy my AngularJS based static site as a Github Page with Yeoman. Step 3 of the deployment instructions tell me to do

`git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages`

but when I enter that I get

`git: 'subtree' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

This [SO answer provided me instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409639/unable-to-update-git-on-ubuntu/17312327#17312327) on how to upgrade to the latest git-core and ensure it  always get upgraded to the latest stable release.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

After running those commands I did `git --version` to make sure I had the latest version and apparently I did since `git version 1.8.3.2` was the output. Now when I tried running

`git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages`

again I still got the same following error

`git: 'subtree' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Finally I just restarted Ubuntu 12.10 and tried to run the command again but once again, I got the same error.

**How come the `git subtree` command is still not working even though I have upgraded to the current stable release?**

Comment: It doesn't seem to be installed by the default package. This site has some directions: http://engineeredweb.com/blog/how-to-install-git-subtree/

Comment: Ahh right thanks. That did it. Feel free to answer it and I will mark it correct if you'd like.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be installed by the default package. This site has some directions: http://engineeredweb.com/blog/how-to-install-git-subtree

Comment: On Ubuntu it was already installed, but I had to add a simlink: http://cogumbreiro.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-install-git-subtree-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: @thebenedict Interesting! BTW building the manpage requires a huge toolchain. I found a patch which adds a pre-built manpage, `git-subtree.1`: http://code.google.com/p/git-core/issues/detail?id=18

Answer (score 47):

It actually is installed on Ubuntu but for some reason it's not put anyplace where git can find it. Easiest way is to create a symlink:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh
sudo ln -s /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh /usr/lib/git-core/git-subtree
```

**UPDATE 1:** looks like a [patch has been submitted](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=704652) upstream to fix this but it hasn't yet been merged.

**UPDATE 2:** the patch to fix this in Debian has been merged, but since they went the route of a separate `git-subtree` package I don't think this will make it to Ubuntu 12.04. Seems to not be an issue in 14.04 as `/usr/lib/git-core/git-subtree` is already created correctly by the `git` package.

Comment: Even after updating to latest from git-core/ppa, subtree is not found. This solution is the real fix for me (Linux Mint 14)

Answer (score 17):

On Fedora, it is available as a separate package:

`dnf install git-subtree`