# Set subdirectory as website root on Github Pages

Tags: git, github, server, webserver, github-pages

I'm using [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/) to host & serve a static website.

The static website has the typical directory structure for an app:

```
.
├ source/
├ build/
│ └ index.html
├ .gitignore
├ config.rb
├ Gemfile
┆ ...
└ README.MD
```

`index.html` is under `build/`, so I want to make that the default `www` path.

So when users hit `username.github.io` it renders the content within that subdirectory and yet it doesn't show "/build/" on the URL, cause that's set as the root folder.

Notes:

- I don't have a custom domain nor planning to get one for this purpose. As you can see, I'm trying to leverage the default URL naming convention github provides.
- Not using [Jekyll](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll) nor the automatic page generator function.

Comment: As indicated at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797328/why-is-the-git-subtree-not-working-even-though-i-have-git-1-8-3-2-installed-on be sure you have git subtree installed.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

There is a detailed gist with all the required steps.

The gist is here:
https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490

---

#### From the gist

> ## Deploying a subfolder to GitHub Pages
>
> Sometimes you want to have a subdirectory on the `master` branch be the root directory of a repository’s `gh-pages` branch. This is useful for things like sites developed with [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io), or if you have a Jekyll site contained in the `master` branch alongside the rest of your code.
>
> For the sake of this example, let’s pretend the subfolder containing your site is named `dist`.
>
> #### Step 1
>
> Remove the `dist` directory from the project’s `.gitignore` file (it’s ignored by default by Yeoman).
>
> #### Step 2
>
> Make sure git knows about your subtree (the subfolder with your site).
>
> ```
> git add dist && git commit -m "Initial dist subtree commit"
> ```
>
> #### Step 3
>
> Use subtree push to send it to the `gh-pages` branch on GitHub.
>
> ```
> git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages
> ```
>
> Boom. If your folder isn’t called `dist`, then you’ll need to change that in each of the commands above.

---

> If you do this on a regular basis, you could also [create a script](https://github.com/cobyism/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/git-gh-deploy) containing the following somewhere in your path:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  echo "Which folder do you want to deploy to GitHub Pages?"
  exit 1
fi
git subtree push --prefix $1 origin gh-pages
```

> Which lets you type commands like:
>
> ```
> git gh-deploy path/to/your/site
> ```

Comment: And thus using this URL convention instead: username.github.io/projectname. Right? 
So that would require renaming the repo to "projectname" instead so I can use the Project Pages setup (https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/), right?

Comment: yep. or you can use custom domain instead

Comment: Alright. I guess this is the only solution. Thanks!

Comment: After further research, there's no way to accomplish what I originally asked. You will need to put the contents of the build folder into the root if you want it to appear at username.github.io. Otherwise use the solution above.

Comment: `gh-deploy` is no longer a valid command. My subfolder is the `public` folder that Firebase asks you to host in by default.

Comment: Hello, is there a way to automatically execute `git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages` via a GitHub action ? If yes, how ?

Answer (score 38):

[Since August 2016](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing) you can use `/docs` subfolder of the `master` branch for your sources.

So if you can tell to your site generator to use `/docs` in place of `/build` you are done (without subtree).

**Note:** As pointed out by @thislooksfun in the comment, this is valid only for project pages (like `<username>.github.io/<projectname>`), but not for user or organization pages (like `<name>.github.io`).

Comment: It's worth noting that this only works with non user/org sites. More specifically, "To publish your site's source files from a /docs folder on your master branch, you must have a master branch and your repository must not follow the repository naming scheme <username>.github.io or <orgname>.github.io" (https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/)

Comment: Also note that it seems if you already have another repository `<username>.github.io` under your account, then the `/docs` won't work. Only looks for index.html directly on `master`. See top of page here: https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/

Answer (score 14):

This is a new solution (in beta).

Go to the Github Pages Settings tab and now change the source to "Github Actions"

[image: Go to the Github Pages Settings tab and now change the source to "Github Actions"]

Next, it will let you pick and configure which action to use (Jekyll, or Static HTML). I chose static HTML, and here is where you need to make a single but important change.

By default, the path is set to '.' (the current directory). You need to change this to the sub-folder that is relevant for you.

[image: By default, the path is set to '.' (the current directory). You need to change this to the sub-folder that is relevant for you.]

In my case, I have a folder called `javadocs` which has the relevant HTML. Now save the changes and either push a commit to main or run the action manually to see the live page!

Comment: For me, when I applied this setup, it still generated a site based on the README.md in the main directory, and putting the subdirectory under the root. Modifying `source` on the `actions/jekyll-build-pages@v1` action did however work like you describe.

Answer (score 3):

Publishing a `dist` folder from `master` branch using **worktree** feature to `gh-pages` branch.

Gist from here: https://gist.github.com/ErickPetru/b1b3138ab0fc6c82cd19ea3a1a944ba6

## Setup

First of all, you need to have a `gh-pages`. If you don't have, create:

```bash
git branch gh-pages
```

This makes a branch based on the `master` HEAD.
It would be okay but the files and the git history of `master` branch are not meaningful on `gh-pages` branch.
Using an `--orphan` branch, you can initialize `gh-pages` in a clean way.

```bash
git checkout --orphan gh-pages
git reset --hard
git commit --allow-empty -m "Init gh-pages branch"
git checkout master
```

Then, mount the branch as a subdirectory using `git worktree`:

```bash
git worktree add dist gh-pages
```

If you didn't ignore the `dist` folder, ignore it so that you don't add generated files accidentally in your `master` branch commits.

```bash
echo "dist/" >> .gitignore
```

## Deploy

Every time you build the static bundle, generated files are in `dist` directory.
Since `dist` folder is now `gh-pages` branch, you can deploy it directly by just creating a commit and pushing it.

```bash
cd dist
git add --all
git commit -m "Deploy on gh-pages updated"
git push origin gh-pages
```

This way nothing was added to the `master` branch history, keeping it clean.

Answer (score 2):

> Somehow for me, the accepted answer only runs the first time. Re-doing it throws errors.

I solved it by running the commands below:

```sh
git checkout --orphan gh-pages
git --work-tree build add --all
git --work-tree build commit -m 'gh-pages'
git push origin HEAD:gh-pages --force
git checkout -f master
```

Comment: error: src refspec HEAD does not match any
It tell me this

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work for gh-pages branch for hugo sites that use a `public/` folder, here is what I have working that is super hacky but gets the job done:

*Note: hugolanding is the folder root where your config.toml is, this script runs from a scripts folder, you could totally move it elsewhere and change that line.*

```
#!/bin/bash
# move to root
cd ../hugolanding
# generate public content
hugo -D
# prep copy folder
rm -rf /tmp/public && mkdir -p /tmp/public
# copy out of git shit
cp -R public/* /tmp/public
# git yolo everything
git add -A 
git commit -m 'updates to public'
git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand
git checkout gh-pages
cd ..
cp -R /tmp/public/* .
git add -A 
git commit -m 'updated gh-pages'
git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand
echo "done"
git checkout main
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `git-worktree`, and deployment from a seperate branch, is a cleaner alternative, since I won't have commits in my `main` branch, intermingled with commits from re-deployment, which I find more succinct, and I won't have to delete the remote branch every time, if I use `git subtree`, which is unnecessary.

`git-worktree` mounts your sub-directory, `dist`, in this example, to a separate branch, `gh-pages`.

Here's how:

```
git branch --track gh-pages origin/gh-pages # Create new gh-pages branch; Add tracking    
git checkout --orphan gh-pages              # Initialize gh-pages without main's history
git reset --hard                            # Remove all history
git commit --allow-empty -m "Init"          # First commit without any files
git checkout main                           # Go back to main (or master) branch
git worktree add dist gh-pages              # Mount dist and bind it to the gh-pages branch
```

`dist` is an `npm` build script which looks like:

```js
"scripts": {
  ...
  "dist": "ng build --configuration production && echo 'gitdir: /home/<user>/<repo>/.git/worktrees/dist' > ./dist/.git"
  ...
}
```

All it does is re-creates the `git-worktree` reference, because the `.git` file in `dist` was removed by `ng build` by default.
This reference is needed by `git` to link `dist` to the index.

And the workflow goes something like this:

```
npm run dist            # Build website with new changes; Removes dist and re-creates it
cd dist                 # Move to gh-pages branch by switching into a directory (cool huh)
git add .               # Add all generated files to staging area
git commit -m "v0.0.3"  # Update the version history of the gh-pages branch
git push                # Push changes to gh-branch
```

If you run `git status` it will reply `On branch  gh-pages`.
And `git log` will show one commit `"Init"`.

But when you `cd ..` and run `git status` again, the response will be `On branch main`.
And `git log` will show all of your original commits to `main`.

So what's happened here is quite interesting. The folder `dist` now has a separate branch, with it's own, unrelated history to `main`,
and all you have to do to switch is `cd dist` to access that branch (`gh-pages`).

This is unlike `git checkout dist`, which would append the `dist` directory, with the auto generated build files to your working tree, intermingling your `main` and deployment histories, which is inconvenient.

Here your `src` files will be untouched, along with their own history in `main`, or `cd ..`, and only the files needed for deployment, will be on this branch, which is really convenient, because it keeps the `src` history seperate from the deployment history.

Now you'd deploy **not** from a folder, but from a branch, which holds the latest compiled version of your site in GitHub pages, and is built from `/(root)`.

> index.html is under build/, so I want to make that the default www path.

Here make certain that the repo that you've created is `<username>.github.io`. I made this same mistake, by having a different repo name, and was frustrated.

> So when users hit username.github.io it renders the content within that subdirectory and yet it doesn't show "/build/" on the URL, cause that's set as the root folder.

Of course there's probably an improvement that could be done here as well.
For example make `npm run dist` do all of this, but my personal preference is to do these steps manually.

Read more about this method [here](https://sangsoonam.github.io/2019/02/08/using-git-worktree-to-deploy-github-pages.html).

But I'd agree, that if you're working on a team, it's probably better to use a tool like [gh-pages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages), to enforce standards in your project.

I hope my explanation is somewhat of a contribution as well, and not just a re-statement of the mentioned methods above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this because you have a **react app** or something similar, the steps described in https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages, will solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

add homepage in package.json like this

```
"homepage": "https://gamingumar.com/watcher",
```

Answer (score -2):

[push-dir](https://github.com/L33T-KR3W/push-dir) will do it:

```
npm install push-direxample
push-dir --dir=build --branch=gh-pages
```