# github project sub-directory redirects to custom domain

Tags: redirect, github, dns, github-pages, subdirectory

I have a github project page here: 
lwymarie.github.io/QPQ_Web/Quasars_Probing_Quasars/Welcome.html

The project is named QPQ_Web. There's an index.html file in it, which points to a Welcome.html file inside the sub-directory Quasars_Probing_Quasars, where all other html files are also stored.

I'd like to replace the entire lwymarie.github.io/QPQ_Web/Quasars_Probing_Quasars/ part of the URL by www.qpqsurvey.org. i.e. I want to skip the Quasars_Probing_Quasars sub-directory in the URL. Please refer to the current www.qpqsurvey.org site to get an idea of what I mean.

Is it possible to set a permalink for this purpose without restructuring my files? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be related to this question: [Set subdirectory as website root on Github Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36782467/set-subdirectory-as-website-root-on-github-pages)

(1) Follow the below instructions to make your subdirectory as GitHub root, then (2) redirect http://www.qpqsurvey.org to gh-pages as you ordinarily would according to GitHub's custom domain instructions: https://help.github.com/articles/using-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/

Copying the answer of @CodeWizard which in turn was cited from https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490 for the first half of my answer:

## Deploying a subfolder to GitHub Pages

Sometimes you want to have a subdirectory on the `master` branch be the root directory of a repository’s `gh-pages` branch. This is useful for things like sites developed with [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io), or if you have a Jekyll site contained in the `master` branch alongside the rest of your code.

For the sake of this example, let’s pretend the subfolder containing your site is named `dist`.

#### Step 1

Remove the `dist` directory from the project’s `.gitignore` file (it’s ignored by default by Yeoman).

#### Step 2

Make sure git knows about your subtree (the subfolder with your site).

```
git add dist && git commit -m "Initial dist subtree commit"
```

#### Step 3

Use subtree push to send it to the `gh-pages` branch on GitHub.

```
git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages
```

Boom. If your folder isn’t called `dist`, then you’ll need to change that in each of the commands above.

---

If you do this on a regular basis, you could also [create a script](https://github.com/cobyism/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/git-gh-deploy) containing the following somewhere in your path:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  echo "Which folder do you want to deploy to GitHub Pages?"
  exit 1
fi
git subtree push --prefix $1 origin gh-pages
```

Which lets you type commands like:

```
git gh-deploy path/to/your/site
```

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: Glad to help. If it works you can accept my answer by ticking the check mark under the upvote-downvote buttons.

Comment: Accepted! Apologize for being a newbie.

Comment: However, what if you want two subdomains redirecting to two subdirectories of your GitPages? You cannot make both subdirectories the root simultaneously. Specifically, how do I get sub1.example.com to redirect username.guthub.io/project1/site1/index.html and sub2.example.com to redirect username.github.io/project2/site2/index.html?