# github pages displaying readme, not index.js

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I have a basic React app. No backend. I want to set it up on github pages. I followed this article, twice. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/surge-vs-github-pages-deploying-a-create-react-app-project-c0ecbf317089

Both times, Github Pages displays the README.md file instead of the index.html file in my public folder. Here is an image of the file directory for the app. Any thoughts?

[image]
Here is what I have in package.json if it matters:

```
{
  "name": "react-blog",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://jackseabolt.github.io/react-blog/",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.14"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy" : "npm run build&&gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36782467/set-subdirectory-as-website-root-on-github-pages

Comment: this does not fix the problem. It's a react project and this answer doesn't appy. It breaks the build

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is likely that you are using your master branch as the source. In the settings tab on your Github project page, change the source to use the gh-pages branch.

See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#step-4-ensure-your-projects-settings-use-gh-pages