# updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote counterpart. git subtree for gh-pages

Tags: node.js, git, tailwind-css, github-pages

I have a branch named `gh-pages` which contains `index.html` because it actually from main branch inside a folder named `public`. I'm using nodejs for tailwindcss, [my directories in main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcJWR.png) so when I'm pushing that certain folder only, I will use the command

```
git subtree push --prefix public origin gh-pages
```

which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36782614/19465528) which normally works. but then today I added a new folder inside it called `tictactoe` which only got HTML and JS file and using `../style.css` from previous directory then I got this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5g0K2.png) which says `updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote counterpart. check out this branch and integrate the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.`.

I tried various solution from this site such as

```
git push -f origin gh-pages
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62603479/19465528) but it says `Everything up-to-date` then I tried pull using `git pull -f origin gh-pages` but it says `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories` so I tried `git pull origin gh-pages --allow-unrelated-histories` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62603479/19465528) which happens it actually pull but I still can't push the subtree normally and receives the same error as this title.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just try the git pull command and then follow all the commit commands.
I will give you step-by-step commands so you got a clear idea of how you can do this.

> git status

> git add "file name"

> git commit -m "msg here"

> git pull

> git push origin your_brnach